# backup a google doc spreadsheet with php & zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, spreadsheet

Hi
Trying to use php to backup a google doc spreadsheet into another (without writing row by row) or to download it like an excel document
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely find the answers in the [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/).

The entry for [copying Google Documents](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CopyingDocs) shows this sample:

> send an HTTP POST to the main feed. In the `<entry>`, set the `<id>` to the self link of the source entry (the document to be copied).

Use PHP to send an HTTP POST request when you have that ID data.

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full/ HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 292
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/document%3Adoc_id</id>
  <title>My Twin</title>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html).